# When you create a free form of Microstrategy, is it possible to do an automatic mapping?

Tags: microstrategy, freeform

When you finish the free form query in microstrategy, the next step is to map the columns.

Is there any way to do it automatically? At least make the list of the columns with its names.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this isn't possible. You will have to map all columns manually.

Answer (score 0):

While this functionality isnt possible with freeform reporting specifically, Microstrategy Data Import will allow you the ability to create Data Import Cubes. These cubes can be configured as live connections, meaning they execute against the data source selected every time they are used, and are not your typical snapshot cube. Data Imports from a database can be sourced from a database query. This effectively allows you to write your own SQL with the end result being a report that you did not have to specify columns manually for.